# How to make React - Router handle backend (expressJS) redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Im trying to visit a route in backend using react router proxy (from 8000 - 8080)

```
`port: 8000,
    proxy: {
        '/api': {
            target: {
                host: "0.0.0.0",
                protocol: 'http:',
                port: 8080
            },
            pathRewrite: {
                '^/api': ''
            }
        }
    }`
```

React anchor link `<a href="/api/auth/google">Google</a>`. this link is being visited on `localhost:8080/auth/google`. 
Now there is redirect on the backend in the above link to `/auth/google/callback`, this is being taken as `localhost:8000/auth/google/callback`, by React Router instead of `localhost:8080/auth/google/callback`.

How to make this redirect happen and get the returned JSON to front end route.